# Dynamically adding form field to angular with reactive form does not render correctly?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

**Problem:**

I have build a reactive form in angular which is dynamically adding a form field when the user clicks on plus button. This is how my code looks like.

```
<form [formGroup]="distributionAddForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(distributionAddForm.value)">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div formArrayName="stocks">
                <div *ngFor="let item of distributionAddForm.controls.stocks.controls; let stockIndex=index"
                    [formGroupName]="stocks">
                    <span>Product Item {{stockIndex + 1}}</span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Stock :</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                            <select class="custom-select" id="stockid" formControlName="stockId">
                                <option value="0">Select Stock Item</option>
                                <option value="1">GOGREEN MEGA 500ml</option>
                                <option value="2">GOGREEN PLUS 500ml</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Quantity :</label>
                                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="nc-icon nc-box"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="10" type="text" formControlName="quantity"
                                        required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removeProducts(stockIndex)"><i
                                    class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-4" (click)="addProducts()"><i
                    class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!distributionAddForm.valid">Add</button>

</form>
```

This is how I have done it in component.ts file.

```
 constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) {
        this.distributionAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            stocks: this.formBuilder.array([this.initStocks()])
        });
    }

    initStocks() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            stockId: ['0', Validators.required],
            quantity: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }


    get AllStockItems(){
        return this.distributionAddForm.get('stocks') as FormArray;
    }

    addProducts() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.distributionAddForm.controls['stocks'];
        control.push(this.initStocks());
    }

    removeProducts(i: number) {
        if(this.AllStockItems.length>1){
            const control = <FormArray>this.distributionAddForm.controls['stocks'];
            control.removeAt(i);
        }

    }
```

When we consider this piece of code in component.html file.`<span>Product Item {{stockIndex + 1}}</span>` stockIndex + 1  is showing the number only in the first input field only. It not showing this number on the dynamically added second input sets. Can someone tell me where I have done wrong?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of stocks, try setting the `formGroupName` to `stockIndex`. Also, could you provide a minimum reproduction in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @julianobrasil changing stocks to stockIndex was worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @julianobrasil Now I want to show the validation error msg. In normal input field we show validation message like following.` <div
                  *ngIf="!agentEditForm.controls['quantity'].valid && (agentEditForm.controls['quantity'].dirty||agentEditForm.controls['lname'].touched)"
                  class="alert alert-danger">Last Name is Required
                </div>`. I want to know how can I show this to this quantity input field in dynamically added form input

Comment: I'll add an answer with both things, with a little demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you do this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of distributionAddForm.controls.stocks.controls; let stockIndex=index" 
     [formGroupName]="stockIndex">
```

About the error message:

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <i class="nc-icon nc-box"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="10" 
         type="text" formControlName="quantity" required>
</div>
<div *ngIf="_showFormArrayError(stockIndex, 'quantity')" 
     class="alert alert-danger">
  Quantity is Required
</div>
```

And in the typescript class:

```js
/** Notice that formGroupName is an index */
_showFormArrayError(formGroupName: number, controlName: string): boolean {
  const formArray: FormArray = this.agentEditForm.get('stocks') as FormArray;
  const formGroup: FormGroup = formArray && 
      formArray.get(`${formGroupName}`) as FormGroup;
  const formControl: FormControl = formGroup && 
      formGroup.get(controlName) as FormControl;

  return (formControl && !formControl.valid && 
         (formControl.dirty | formControl.touched));
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma614406726433166)